# webapi to IoTHub not working from Azure deployment

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-iot-hub

was: "Iot Hub diagnostics azure deployed app"

Strange issue.  I have a very simple 4.5.2 based webapi application that acts as a field gateway; that is each method connects to IoT Hub on behalf of the consumer which are actual devices capable of only posting to HTTP endpoints.

When I run the code from my local development machine everything works as expected and my IoT Hub receives the data.  so, then, I published the webapi application to azure and ran the same methods but there is no activity to the IoT Hub detected at all. weird. I went so far as to debug the application code in azure and everything is working without error.  There's no external configuration to mess things up at the moment, its all in the code.

Is there are logical explanation for this behavior?

I'm new to IoT Hub so maybe this is a simple thing.  Where can I turn on verbose diagnostics?  Since I have code that I believe to be working where can I see the next logical information?  Are there permissions of some sort that may be preventing the data to pass through?

WebApi method(s) basically call this code which is contained in a separate assembly

```
    public static void SendTempData(string Name, string value)
    {
        var telemetryDataPoint = new
        {
            deviceId = HOME_TEMP_DEVICE,
            DeviceName = Name,
            TValue = value
        };

        var messageString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(telemetryDataPoint);
        var task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            deviceClient = DeviceClient.Create(iotHubUri, new DeviceAuthenticationWithRegistrySymmetricKey(HOME_TEMP_DEVICE, HOME_TEMP_DEVICE_KEY), TransportType.Mqtt);

            var message = new Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messageString));

            deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message);
        });

        WaitForTask(ref task);

        CheckForFail(task);
    }

    private static void WaitForTask(ref Task task)
    {
        while (task.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
        {
            if ((task.IsCanceled) || (task.IsFaulted))
                break;

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Thread ID: {0}, Status: {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, task.Status);
        }
    }
```

Bottom line is I have no visibility.  Is there some verbose setting I can enable to see why IoTHub never sees a connection or data?

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: I edited the original post to show the code.  I originally had trouble running the async code in the web service which is why you see the additional debug code.

Comment: I never solved this problem, but, I did get a .Net version 1.1 implementation working with the new azure.device.client SDK that supports 1.1 and it works correctly when deployed to azure.  no code changes required; just the new SDK reference.

Comment: What's the version of azure.devices.client SDK works for you?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT, the team released 2.9.1 in April.  When i modified my code to use the newer version SDK everything worked as expected.